# Find a VPN Name on a Cisco ASA box given a remote IP address

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA box with multiple site-to-site VPNs defined.

Is there a way to automate finding the VPN name based on a given remote IP address?

Comment: What do you mean?  Like find the Connection Name on the ASA under the Connection Profile?  By default it is the same as the Peer IP Address.  Not sure what you are looking for to be honest.

Comment: Yes, finding the peer IP address, or an access-list would be great.

Comment: I still don't know what you are after.  What do mean by "automate"?  What is the end goal here?  Are you trying to gather it from a remote app (if so, which one)?  I guess I'm lost as to why remoting into the ASA once, writing down the VPNs, and then documenting them somewhere isn't sufficient.  Or just dumping the config as it changes and parsing the appropriate section.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?